# how do you undo a few operations in the vi editor

Tags: undo-redo

i have just tried something of which i don't know how it worked out but thanks it did. i have been trying to undo a few operations of dl which deleted a few letters. it didn't work as it kept on redoing so i tried something else. i then kept on pressing random numbers with a "u" and those letters came back. e.g 9u

how does this work?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Are you asking how the underlying undo mechanism works, how to undo (press `u`), or how to undo multiple operations? Please [edit] your question to clarify, and see the [formatting guide](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: the original vi editor only had one single undo operation. Then there were a few vi clones, that allowed `.` to repeat going further undo IIRC.

Answer (score 5):

**Original vi** only supports single-level undo: the first time you press `u` it performs an undo, and the second time you press it it *undoes* the undo, going back to the state before the undo.

**Nvi** (and possibly other implementations of vi) allow you to perform more undoes first by pressing `u`, and then by pressing `.` to repeat the undo *operation*.

**Vim** augments undo with [two different undo behaviours](https://vimhelp.org/undo.txt.html#undo-two-ways).

In “vi-compatible” undo, the `u` key behaves as above. If, however, you want to perform multiple undo operations, you first press `u` to undo, and then press `Ctrl-R` for further undoes.

In the Vim-style undo, pressing `u` will always go backwards through the undolist, and pressing `Ctrl-R` will always go forwards.

To switch from vi-compatible to Vim-style, you add the [`u` flag to your `'cpoptions'` setting](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#cpo-u), but the most common way of doing this is by abandoning [vi compatibility](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27compatible%27) entirely, which is generally achieved simply by creating a .vimrc file*.

If you want to stop using vi compatibility in an existing session, you can use the command:

```
:set nocompatible
```

<sub>* Or by upgrading Vim past version 7.4.2111, which switches off `'compatible'` in its `defaults.vim` script.</sub>